# Is there a way to use Mongo/Morphia without org.bson.types.ObjectId?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

[Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) is a persistence library for the JVM, used when your app needs to communicate with a MongoDB. When you use it, apparently in Mongo/Morphia land, this unique ID needs to be a [`org.bson.types.ObjectId`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html).

**Is this true?** Is there any reason why I can't use a `Long` for the ID, such as in:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class WidgetEntity {
    @Id
    Long id

    // ...etc.
}
```

If it *is* possible to just use a `Long`, then what am I giving up by using a `Long` instead of an `ObjectId`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Long` but in this case you need to assign a value yourself.

From the morphia [quickstart sample](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/QuickStart):

> Also note that we had to add a new field "id" to our Hotel class. The
>   "id" value can be any persist-able type; like an int, uuid, or other
>   object. If you want an auto-generated value just declare it as an
>   ObjectId. If you don't use an ObjectId you must set the value before
>   saving.

Comment: Ahh gotchya thanks @wero (+1), can you please just confirm: `Long` is perfectly fine, but I need my own auto-incrementing mechanism, yes? If so, does Morphia (or anyone else) provide a auto-incrementer for these ids?

Comment: yes, you might find this useful http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/